# Angular2 back and forward button of browser not working with queryparams

Tags: angular

I'm using Leaflet on a Angular project. There are a navigation, sub navigation and a map on the project. You can see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-routing-2. When click on the map `onMapClick` is called and lat and long values added the url. When location changes back and forward button of browser not change marker location. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Event } from "@angular/router";
declare let L;

@Component({
  selector: "app-map-report",
  templateUrl: "./map-report.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./map-report.component.css"]
})
export class MapReportComponent implements OnInit {
  lat;
  lng;
  map;
  marker;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.lat = params["lat"] ? params["lat"] : 52.520008;
      this.lng = params["lng"] ? params["lng"] : 13.404954;
      this.renderMarker();
    });
  }

  initMap() {
    const lat = this.lat ? this.lat : 52.520008;
    const lng = this.lat ? this.lng : 13.404954;
    this.map = new L.Map("mapReport", {
      zoomControl: true,
      maxZoom: 20,
      minZoom: 2,
      center: new L.LatLng(lat, lng),
      zoom: 10
    });
    this.map.zoomControl.setPosition("bottomright");
    const tileLayers = {
      Google: L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&hl=tr&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
        {
          subdomains: ["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"],
          maxNativeZoom: 20,
          zIndex: 0,
          maxZoom: 20
        }
      ).addTo(this.map)
    };

    this.marker = L.marker(this.map.getCenter(), {
      draggable: true,
      highlight: "permanent",
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
        iconSize: [30, 35],
        iconAnchor: [30 / 2, 35]
      })
    }).addTo(this.map);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map.invalidateSize();
    }, 300);
    this.map.on("click", this.onMapClick.bind(this));
  }
  onMapClick(e) {
    this.lat = e.latlng.lat;
    this.lng = e.latlng.lng;
    this.renderMarker();
  }

  renderMarker() {
    this.marker.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng));
    this.map.panTo(new L.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng));
    this.router.navigate([], {
      queryParams: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
      relativeTo: this.route
    });
  }
}
```

You need to unsubscribe all the subscriptions on the component destroy event otherwise it may create some annoying behavior on the other pages.

Comment: Thanks for answer its working but if there is no queryparams redirect is working. I dont need to use redirect